# ffmpeg webm to png thumbnail (with alpha channel support)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert my webm video with transparent background into a thumbnail with the same transparent background.

Right now what I do is:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i public/files/461b10f8-b866-474b-b079-60fbdfbb553b/461b10f8-b866-474b-b079-60fbdfbb553b.webm -ss 00:00:00.01 -vframes 1 -vf scale=320:-1:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease out.png
```

but my conversion fails. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
 Metadata:
COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: isomiso2avc1mp41
MAJOR_BRAND     : isom
MINOR_VERSION   : 512
ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.01, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 749 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 3), none(tv, progressive), 320x568, SAR 1:1 DAR 40:71, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libvpx
      DURATION        : 00:00:01.007000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : Core Media Audio
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.134.100 libopus
      DURATION        : 00:00:01.006000000
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc27984ae00] v1.11.0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (libvpx-vp9) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc27984ae00] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc27984ae00] Failed to decode frame: Bitstream not supported by this decoder
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it turned out that I had a webm video with `pix_fmt = yuv420p10le` and it wasn't supported with my version of ffmpeg.
You could get the list of supported pixel formats with command:

`ffmpeg -help encoder=libvpx-vp9`